# Running a function in a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a simulator which rolls a 6 sided dice:

```
def diceRoll6():
    return random.randint(1,6)
```

and now I want to repeat this roll with a for loop, but also to be able to change which simulator I am using in the function, e.g. maybe I have another function which rolls 2 dice and takes the product.

```
def frequencies(sim,n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = sim
        output.append(result)
    return output
```

However whenever I run `frequencies(diceRoll6(),10)` it just has the same output 10 times, rather than running the simulator 10 separate times and getting different outputs.

Comment: You only called `diceRoll6` once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also dont execute the sim function in the for loop. so your actually passing the result of the function to frequencies rather than the function its self.

So your saying execute the diceroll function, get its result and pass that to frequencies. Instead you need to pass the func to it without the `()` so that your passing a reference to the func not its result.

So frequencies is just receiving the int value from diceroll and the n times. So it will append that int n times to the list

you need to pass the dice roll function not its result to frequency and have frequency function execute it for you n times.

```py
import random

def diceRoll6():
    return random.randint(1,6)

def frequencies(sim,n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = sim()
        output.append(result)
    return output

print(frequencies(diceRoll6, 10))
```

you could also simply your frequencies function to be something like

```py
def frequencies(sim,n):
    return [sim() for _ in range(n)]
```

Comment: I made a typo when writing my question, but the append is within the for loop

Comment: ah ok updated to remove that part. In short your issue is you execute the function and only pass the result to frequency. you need to pass the function as a reference and let frequncy for loop execute it each loop.

Comment: Ahhh I've just realised my mistake! I needed to not have the diceRoll6 without the brackets after in the final function, then have sim() rather than sim

Comment: `diceRoll6()` will call that function and get the return value. I.E lets say 5. then what was actually being bassed to frequency was 5 and 10, so you just got 10 of the same number. by passing just `diceRoll6` without brackets, your passing a refernce to the function. then in the loop where `sim` is the reference to `dicRoll6` you call that function to get a new result each time `sim()`

Answer (score 0):

Passing a function into another function as a variable is fine and you did it correctly here. When you call `frequencies(diceRoll6,10)`, `sim=diceRoll6`. However, in the loop you set `result=sim` and then append `result` which means you are appending the function `diceRoll6` 10 times when you instead want to call `diceRoll6` and append the result.

Try:

```
def frequencies(sim,n):
    output = []
    for i in range(n):
        result = sim()
        output.append(result)
    return output
```

Comment: I made a typo in my original post with the indent on the append line, but what you've written is exactly what I have and it still appends the same result 10 times

Comment: Just noticed the difference actually, I had sim, not sim()